# c# Embed Resource dll

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll

I have a function that need a dll Resource

```
    using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=logindata;Version=3;"))
    {
    }
```

it requires : **SQLite.Interop.dll**

so instead of putting that dll in the same Enviroment folder i use it as an embedded resource :

```
   [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("EmbedAssembly.SQLite.Interop.dll"))
            {
                byte[] Data = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(Data, 0, Data.Length);
                return Assembly.Load(Data);

            }
        }
```

But it still throw an exception :

```
Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

**EDIT** : Solved by adding the whole new class to the project instead of refering to it as a dll reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the whole new Sqlite Class to my project instead of adding it on my project as a reference .